# Best Practices: Transferring millions of entries to another MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, data-transfer

I have the following task assigned to me:

Take a current database, with multiple tables and hundreds of thousands of entries and write a script that will transfer much of this data to a separate database with a different structure.

Basically a new database has been created with a different table structure, and I need to (after confirming that all the datatypes will match up) write a script to copy the data over to the correct table/column.

Ultimately I was wondering on such a massive data transfer is there are any best practices, preferred languages, or hints/tips that someone could give?

Answer (score 1):

To start, I think the most important take-away is that you should at all costs avoid writing up any scripts that will transfer your data from a production server to another. The potential dangers of working with your live data for a migration alone should be enough reason.

That said, I can advise a few practices I think might be good for such a task.

1. Take all the data from your production server and dump it to a devbox that is completely and entirely separate. Abolish the risk to your original data as well as performance impact to the server.
2. Once on a strictly-development rig, I'd recommend if at all possible to keep all your data movement from SQL to SQL, rather than scripting it in some intermediary language.  Of course, your new structure might be entirely prohibiting this sort of approach, but in general, having to worry about moving data from a strict, dependable datatype to another language (e.g., a typeless PHP or a type-strict .net) back to a database is adding a number of steps that complicate your task, add computational hours, and potentially uncaught lossiness.
3. Spend as much time verifying the intelligence of the new design schema as you have time and power to do so. Unless your hands are tied, try to visualize if the changes are--in fact--improvements and that the inevitable query re-writes improve efficiency and readability.

I'm sure there are a number of other things to be looking out for, but I hope these are sufficiently helpful in helping you move from one schema to the next. Don't bog yourself down with remote servers if a local one is plausible and then import. Keep it simple!